# Hidden template row taking values from javascript populated rows in repeater on postback

Tags: javascript, vb.net, repeater

I have been working on a dynamic user interface screen where part of it is a table that needs to have a dynamic number of rows. I decided to approach this by duplicating a "template" row which is hidden to create new rows.

```
                                <table id="tblLocations">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="tbH" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td class="tbH" nowrap><asp:Label ID=rptLocations_Hdr_Aisle runat=server Text="Aisle" /></td>
                                            <td class="tbH" nowrap><asp:Label ID=rptLocations_Hdr_Rack runat=server Text="Rack" /></td>
                                            <td class="tbH" nowrap><asp:Label ID=rptLocations_Hdr_Level runat=server Text="Level" /></td>
                                            <td class="tbH" nowrap><asp:Label ID=rptLocations_Hdr_OrigQty runat=server Text="Existing Qty" /></td>
                                            <td class="tbH" nowrap><asp:Label ID=rptLocations_Hdr_Qty runat=server Text="New Qty" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr runat="server" id="tblLocations_SampleRow" style="display:none;"> 
                                            <td nowrap class="tbD" align="center"><asp:HiddenField runat=server ID=hfLocationsID_Sample /></td>
                                            <td nowrap class="tbD" align="center"><asp:Textbox ID="lbl_LocationsAisle_Sample" runat="server" /></td>
                                            <td nowrap class="tbD" align="center"><asp:Textbox ID="lbl_LocationsRack_Sample" runat="server"  /></td>
                                            <td nowrap class="tbD" align="center"><asp:Textbox ID="lbl_LocationsLevel_Sample" runat="server"  /></td>
                                            <td nowrap class="tbD" align="center"><asp:Textbox ID="lbl_LocationsOrigQty_Sample" runat="server"  Enabled=false /></td>
                                            <td nowrap class="tbD" align="center"><asp:Textbox ID="lbl_LocationsQty_Sample" runat="server"  /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptLocations">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <tr runat="server" id=trData>
                                                <td nowrap class="tbD" align="center"><asp:HiddenField runat=server ID=hfLocationsID /></td>
                                                <td nowrap class="tbD" align="center"><asp:Textbox ID="lbl_LocationsAisle" runat="server" /></td>
                                                <td nowrap class="tbD" align="center"><asp:Textbox ID="lbl_LocationsRack" runat="server" /></td>
                                                <td nowrap class="tbD" align="center"><asp:Textbox ID="lbl_LocationsLevel" runat="server" /></td>
                                                <td nowrap class="tbD" align="center"><asp:Textbox ID="lbl_LocationsOrigQty" runat="server" /></td>
                                                <td nowrap class="tbD" align="center"><asp:Textbox ID="lbl_LocationsQty" runat="server" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                </table>
```

I am using the following Javascript to add a first row, then a second if the first row has existing data.

```
            function LoadLocationsList(rrRow) {
                    var inputs = rrRow.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input');
                    var tds = rrRow.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('td');

                    var table = document.getElementById('tblLocations');
                    var row = document.getElementById('tblLocations_SampleRow');

                    var ClonedRow = null;
                    ClonedRow = row.cloneNode(true);


                    ClonedRow.style.display = "";

                    var RowID = table.rows.length-1;
                    var ExistingAisle = inputs[3].value;
                    var ExistingRack = inputs[4].value;
                    var ExistingLevel = inputs[5].value;
                    var ExistingQty = inputs[2].value;
                    var ExistingNewQty = inputs[2].value;

                    ClonedRow.id = 'tblLocations_Row' + RowID;

                    ClonedRow.cells[0].firstChild.value = RowID;

                    if (ExistingQty > 0) {
                        ClonedRow.cells[1].firstChild.innerText = ExistingAisle;
                        ClonedRow.cells[2].firstChild.innerText = ExistingRack;
                        ClonedRow.cells[3].firstChild.innerText = ExistingLevel;
                        ClonedRow.cells[4].firstChild.innerText = ExistingQty;
                        ClonedRow.cells[5].firstChild.innerText = ExistingNewQty;

                        table.appendChild(ClonedRow);

                        ClonedRow = null;
                        ClonedRow = row.cloneNode(true);
                        ClonedRow.style.display = "";
                        RowID = table.rows.length-1;
                        ClonedRow.id = 'tblLocations_Row' + RowID;
                    }

                    table.appendChild(ClonedRow);


                }
```

rrRow is a repeater row which is passed in to the event by an OnClientClick event on that row. The data is coming through fine - and it all appears to be doing exactly what I want. The problem is that when I click another button which opens a modal popup (I believe this is triggering a postback) somehow that Sample Row is altered to contain the data that the rptLocations repeater item rows had. It also puts commas between the data. So the first time I do it, it might say "F4" which is correct. If I trigger the same javascript funtion again, though, it will do the first row properly, but when it puts in a second row that is supposed to be blank, it looks like "F4,F4". If I open the modal and close it again without making a selection, then inspect, I can see the sample row has somehow picked up data.

I am not interacting with that sample row anywhere except for that Javascript function. Here is what I am clicking on to cause the sample row values to change.

```
<asp:Button ID=btnSearchProduct runat=server Text="Search Products" OnClientClick="Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(popEvent_SearchProduct);" />
```

---

```
function popEvent_SearchProduct() {
                    $('#modalInfoX').reveal({
                         animation: 'fadeAndPop',                   //fade, fadeAndPop, none
                        animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
                        closeonbackgroundclick: true,              //if you click background will modal close?
                        dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal'    //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
                    });

         Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().remove_endRequest(popEvent_SearchProduct);
                }
```

---

```
 <asp:Panel ID="pnModal_ProductSearch" runat="server" Visible="false" DefaultButton="btnSearch_Cancel">
                <div id="modalInfoX" class="reveal-modal xlarge">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID=upProductSearch runat=server>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <h1>Product Search<br />
                            <asp:DropDownList ID=ddSearch_OMS runat=server></asp:DropDownList> <br />
                            <asp:TextBox ID=txtSearch_ProductBox runat=server Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Button ID=btnSearch_Search runat=server Text="Search" />
                            <br />

                           <Table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="tbH" nowrap><asp:LinkButton ID=lbSortProduct_OMS OnClick="SortProduct_OMS_Click"  runat=server CssClass="link_Sort">OMS</asp:LinkButton></td>
                                    <td class="tbH" nowrap><asp:LinkButton ID=lbSortProduct_ItemNumber OnClick="SortProduct_ItemNumber_Click"  runat=server CssClass="link_Sort">Product ID</asp:LinkButton></td>
                                    <td class="tbH" nowrap><asp:LinkButton ID=lbSortProduct_Description OnClick="SortProduct_Description_Click"  runat=server CssClass="link_Sort">Product Description</asp:LinkButton></td>
                                </tr>

                                <asp:Repeater ID="rptProductSearch" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <tr id="trData" runat="server">
                                            <td nowrap class="tbD" align="center"><asp:HiddenField runat=server ID=hfSearchProductID Value=0 /> <asp:HiddenField runat=server ID=hfSearchProductWeight /> <asp:HiddenField runat=server ID=hfSearchQty Value=0 /> <asp:HiddenField runat=server ID=hfSearchAisle /><asp:HiddenField runat=server ID=hfSearchRack /><asp:HiddenField runat=server ID=hfSearchLevel /><asp:Label ID="lbl_OMS" runat="server" /></td>
                                            <td nowrap class="tbD" align="left"><asp:LinkButton ID="lbl_ItemNumber" runat="server" OnClientClick="ProductSelected(this); return false;" /></td>
                                            <td nowrap class="tbD" align="left"><asp:Label ID="lbl_ItemDescription" runat="server" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                 </asp:Repeater>

                            </Table>


                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch_Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClientClick="$('#modalInfoX').trigger('reveal:close');" /> 

                    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
```

All I have to do to get the sample row to pick up data from the other table rows is to click the btnSearchProduct button and then close the modal popup. All rows disappear without running my javascript, but I can still inspect that template row and see it's values have changed.

I don't need a complete solution here, I can figure it out, I just would really love to know if anyone knows any behaviors which would result in a comma delimited list of values like that on the sample row, so I can focus my debugging efforts.

Thanks